# using Get-TfsItemHistory in powershell to get specific property values

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-workitem

I am using powershell to try to make a email script that will send out a list of changesets and affected work items for the latest build

I am doing this with

```
Get-TfsItemHistory WorkspacePath -Version "LBuild 9.1.71.1~LBuild 9.1.72.1" -Recurse |
    Select * -exp WorkItems | 
    Format-Table Committer,ChangesetId,Comment,Id,Title -GroupBy ChangesetId -Auto
```

I am trying to use this information to populate a table in the email

How can I get a specific value such as the 4th changeset's Commiter value

I would like to find a way I can put this into a loop to search for

N changeset's Committer,ChangesetId,Comment,Id, and Title vlaue

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate with this case:[return Get-TfsItemHistory specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345220/return-get-tfsitemhistory-specific-value)

If you want to select this Changeset, also suggest you to use `Select-Object`

Since your have mentioned you want to get N changeset's Committer,ChangesetId,Comment,Id, and Title value. I was wondering if you want to make a customization to display this information. You can use `$_.committer`. Please review this blog for more detail steps: http://edwinfrey.com/blog/2012/06/02/tfs-history-reporting-with-powershell/