# return Get-TfsItemHistory specific value

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-power-tools

I am using powershell to try to make a email script that will send out a list of changesets and affected work items for the latest build

I am doing this with

```
Get-TfsItemHistory WorkspacePath -Version "LBuild 9.1.71.1~LBuild 9.1.72.1" -Recurse |
    Select * -exp WorkItems | 
    Format-Table Committer,ChangesetId,Comment,Id,Title -GroupBy ChangesetId -Auto
```

How can I get a specific value such as the 4th changeset's Commiter value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pipe to the Select-Object cmdlet

```
Get-TfsItemHistory WorkspacePath -Version "LBuild 9.1.71.1~LBuild 9.1.72.1" -Recurse | Select * -exp WorkItems | Select-Object -First 1 -Skip 3 | Select-Object -Property Committer
```

This should only pull out the 4th item and only return the Committer.